# JQuery changing css background color

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

i just stared working with JQuery for the first time and i have a simple question about changing css, this is my current code but i would like to be able to prompt for the color how can this be achieved?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#change").click(function() {
        $("#container").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

ive tried this:

```
<input id="colorInput" type="text"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#change").click(function() {
        $("#container").css("background-color", #colorInput);
});
```

And alot of other ways but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean "prompt", generally that means something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/a3vX6/**

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#container").css("background-color", #colorInput);
```

to

```
$("#colorInput").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
```

id or class of element to be effected will be in selector.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wygg/95/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#change").click(function() {
$("#container").css("background-color", $("#colorInput").val());
});
```

You can get the value from that input using

```
$("#colorInput").val()
```

Comment: @user3142531 accept Anoop's answer if that worked :) so the question can be removed from unanswered questions' list.

Answer (score 0):

If your colorinput is like as `#FF00AA` then use as below

```
 $("#container").css("background-color", $("#colorInput").val());
```

else use as below:

```
 $("#container").css("background-color", "#"+$("#colorInput").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

created something on jsfiddle.

check the link : http://jsfiddle.net/SE5R2/2/

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#change').click(function () {
        $('#box').css({
            'background-color': '#' + $('#color').val()
        });
    });
});`